# What's the best way to achieve an oblique background layout?

Tags: css, svg

I would like to obtain the same result as the image below
[image: Oblique layout]

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: if use the svg tag, i guess you are using an svg for background  ... what is the question? ... your issue is about ?

Comment: I would save the gray pattern as vector graphic and display it in the back. As overlay I would use a linear-gradient which contains the white overlay and the grey line.

Comment: @GCyrillus: I thought svg could be a solution (for the shape to the right, for example), so I used the svg tag. The issue is mainly how to develop that layout in html/css.

Comment: @Stephan: Thanks for the reply. How can I give the same rotation for the line and the gray pattern? Can You provide me an example?

Comment: Maybe your question will fit here https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css better, since you ask for recommandation somehow ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said you could use a tiled vector image as main background and a linear gradient (like `linear-gradient(100deg, white 15%, gray 15%, gray 15.1%, white 15.1%, white 78%, transparent 78%)`) as overlay.

I made a small sample at [codepen](https://codepen.io/stephtr/pen/EvYgRy) (with a solid color as background), just as an idea to start (scaling it to different window sizes has to be done according to your content.

Comment: Thanks! Just what i needed! :)